HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error (The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly)
This error occurs only in certain page that load with a lot of data. Other page with same module is run with no error.
ERROR 500
this using php 7.2 and codeigniter. please help
is there any issus with size? Microsoft Visual C++ is already install in server.

Please make sure you have installed Visual C++ Redistributable:
Visual C++ Redistributable.
And this error may also be missing the correct VC++ runtime for the version of PHP you are running, so please choose the VC++ runtime corresponding to PHP 7.2 version.
